# code 128 barcode font not displaying in pdf

Tags: java, barcode, birt, code128

I have made reports using BIRT report designer by eclipse.
I want to generate code 128 barcode via font. In my Report Viewer, barcode is working well. But when I exported it into Java (calling the birt report viewer to display), it did not display as barcode. It is displayed a plain text.

I already installed code 128 font in my windows system's font.
Do I need to install something else?

regards, yanyan

Comment: *What am I missing here?* - some code

Comment: *"What am I missing here?"* - The font?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I already have the font installed.

Comment: @ScaryWombat As far as I know, I only need this code: 
public void LoadtransShipment(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent event) {m_browse = "http://localhost:50000/WebViewerExample/frameset?__report=transShipment.rptdesign&No_="+getVendNo();}

Comment: @yanyan Yes, but is the font available to the PDF?  Jasper Reports has a similar issue with custom fonts

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes, It was displayed in BIRT but whenever I call BIRT in my java, it displayed as a plain text only which is the data of barcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You install font in your System? But did you install it in your tomcat? if not, then that would be the problem. You need to copy code 128 into tomcat.